# How to end loop with outside function in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops

I have problem with ending loop by outside function. This is for my tick tack toe game.
Below is part of my code, my function win(x) with conditions to win, and I would like it to finish the "while game" loop. I tried many ways, it does print "X wins" if conditions of win_x() are met, but the loop keeps going as by range(5)
How can I change the win_x() function to end loop?

```
def win_x():
  global game
  global win
  global board_numbers
  if board_numbers[30]=="X" and board_numbers[62]=="X" and board_numbers[94]=="X":
    os.system('clear')
    print(board_numbers)
    print("X wins")


game=True
while game:
  os.system('clear')
  print(board_numbers)
  for i in range(5):
    if player_marker=="X" or player_marker=="x":
      player_X()
      os.system('clear')
      win_x()
      computer_O()

    else:
      os.system('clear')
      computer_X()
      player_O()
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `game` to `False` in `win_x` or somewhere else?

Comment: You can return a boolean from win_x, which tells whether the game has been finished or not. Have an 'if' check, and use 'break' statement to exit.

Comment: Where did the numbers `30`, `62` and `94` come from?

Comment: "Where did the numbers 30, 62 and 94 come from?"
Position of corresponding numbers 1, 5 and 9 on the board

"Have you tried setting game to False in win_x or somewhere else? – mkrieger1 3 mins ago"
I have tried and failed

"You can return a boolean from win_x, which tells whether the game has been finished or not. Have an 'if' check, and use 'break' statement to exit. "
Tried it this way and it didn't work,

Comment: Also tried to create global variable "win" with value  of 0 and then adding 1 if condition of win_x() is met and then in while loop I did "if win==1: break" and still didn't work. Also tried with google, etc and still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept trying and I figured it out. code looks silly but works:

```
def win_x():
  global game
  global board_numbers
  if board_numbers[30]=="X" and board_numbers[62]=="X" and board_numbers[94]=="X":
    os.system('clear')
    print(board_numbers)
    print("X wins")
    game=False     #placing just game=False on its own didn't help

game=True

while game:
  os.system('clear')
  print(board_numbers)
  for i in range(5):
    if player_marker=="X" or player_marker=="x":
      player_X()
      os.system('clear')
      win_x()
      if game==False:    #it is still weird as game=False was in above function
        break            #so I am not sure why I had to state it here
      computer_O()

    else:
      os.system('clear')
      computer_X()
      player_O()
```